# How to split a string in desired format in php

Tags: php, regex

I've a string like below

```
$num = "20142311.235504";
```

I want to  split the string in below format

```
$date['year'] = 2014;
$date['Month'] = 23;
$date['day'] = 11;
$date['hour'] = 23;
$date['min'] = 55;
$date['sec'] = 04;
```

or even in date form like below

```
2014/23/11 23:55:04
```

I tried using `preg_split('/(d{4})/',$num,$matches);` and `str_split` but am not getting the desired output. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Perg split give you matching with same pattern, but you need is dynamic index and dynamic length of data. So if you have data consistency then do fetch data by index. If you have format like this `2014/23/11 23:55:04` then you can parse it by Date classes

Comment: Try with https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php maybe : your format is something like `Ymd.His`, transform it as date then play with it no ?

Comment: Month = `23`? I think you swapped day with month

Comment: @ka_lin that is how it feels when you are waiting for something in January

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is a date, you can do this :

```
$num = "20142311.235504";

// You create a date with your string according to your current format
$date = date_create_from_format("Ydm.His", $num);

// Now you can play with it
$formattedDate = $date->format("Y/d/m H:i:s"); // `string(19) "2014/23/11 23:55:04"` 

$dateTest['year']  = $date->format("Y"); // 2014
$dateTest['Month'] = $date->format("m"); // 11
$dateTest['day']   = $date->format("d"); // 23
$dateTest['hour']  = $date->format("H"); // 23
$dateTest['min']   = $date->format("i"); // 55
$dateTest['sec']   = $date->format("s"); // 04
```

Demo here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Answer (score 0):

With the help of regex you can do this. In pattern create capture group for garbing year, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds. Simple [**example**](https://3v4l.org/FCSGt):

```
$str = "20142311.235504";
preg_match('~^(?<year>\d{4})(?<day>\d{2})(?<month>\d{2}).(?<hour>\d{2})(?<minute>\d{2})(?<second>\d{2})$~', $str, $match);

echo '<pre>', print_r($match);
```

But I prepare you to use `date_create_from_format()` which is more easier and faster than regex. First, convert a known date format separated by `-`, explode that format to convert an array and finally assign the array to a set of key [by array_combine()].  [**Example**](https://3v4l.org/3d3vG):

```
$str = "20142311.235504";
$match = array_combine(['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second'], explode('-', (date_create_from_format("Ydm.His", $str))->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s')));
echo '<pre>', print_r($match);
```